# Moving the Caret with OS X Text Substitution

Tags: macos, text

You can set up text substitutions in OS X in the Languages and Text tab of System Preferences.

Is there a way to choose where the caret will appear after a text substitution takes place?

For example, when I type `thx` I want it to expand to `Thank you |.` where the `|` character represents where I would like the caret to be after the text has been substituted.

Right now when I set the shortcut `thx` to expand to `Thank you .`, and I type `thx`, it gets replaced with `Thank you . |`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. You might add a snippet like this in TextExpander though:

```
Thank you %|.
```

Or use [DefaultKeyBinding.dict](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html):

```
{
    "\UF704" = { // F1
        "t" = {
            "h" = {
                "x" = (insertText:, "Thank you .", moveBackward:);
            };
        };
    };
}
```